# How to set and configure server WWW with apache2 (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, apache2

So, I've been said to set and configure virtual WWW server on virtualbox, where one machine is a server and 2nd is the client. Server has 2 internet cards, where client only one. Server's first card must have bridged connection, where 2nd one is local connection.

Client only has card with local connection. I shouldnt download anything except apache2. Server has connection to DHCP (thru bridge), where client only to the sites that my WWW server possess. I have tried to make it by my own but simply cant figure it out nor find something useful in the internet. Can anybody help me out? I can give screenshots of the progress I already made and would be glad for anyone's help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Description is bit weird, I assume "bridged" connection is one that is connected to hist and outside networks, while local is probably internal VM onky network.

Didn't say which hypervisor so I'll assume you know hiw to setup VMs.

In general way, create two virtual switches, one "internal only", one bridged.

Create two VMs, on one connect just internal-VM-network, on other connect both virtual networks.

Boot installer and install OS (or maybe you have preconfigured VM images, then use those)

On client no need to do anything, just setup static IP, as you don't mention other servers/routers, so no DHCP. Set eg. 10.10.10.11

On server, set static IP on INTERNAL VM adapter, eg 10.10.10.9. we will assume other adapter (bridged) has DHCP or they provided IP details for you, so set that.

On server open terminal or if it's real server just write in terminal / console

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

After it's done make sure Apache isnup vy writing

```
service apache2 start
service apache2 status
```

Your website goes to

```
/var/www/html/index.htm
```

Your website config goes to

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available
```

Open web from clients browser by typing

```
http://10.10.10.9/
```

If this is homework assignment then consult your lab scripts. If it's work assignment consult your mentor and search on based on what I wrote above.

Good luck and keep on trying!